# Подлагивания аудио воспроизводимого MediaPlayer'ом JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, аудио, mediaplayer

Я воспроизвожу аудио прямо из сети. Таким образом, если использовать, например, какой-нибудь браузер, то воспроизводимое аудио начинает на некоторых моментах подлагивать, прерываться. Как это исправляется?

Comment: Расширением канала связи? :)))

Comment: @kot-da-vinci могу открыть хоть 8 вкладок в браузере с видео в 720р и включить любой трек в всё том же браузере и никаких лагов не будет, тут скорее вина процессора, т.к. заметил, что лагать начинает например тогда, когда я открываю код какого-нибудь большого класса в IDE